# Python Write Temp File to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am currently trying to write a dataframe to a temp file and then upload that temp file into an S3 bucket. When I run my code there currently isn't any action that occurs. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The following is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import tempfile
import os 

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id = access_key, aws_secret_access_key = secret_key, region_name = region)

temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
largedf.to_csv(temp, sep = '|')
s3.put_object(temp, Bucket = '[BUCKET NAME]', Key = 'test.txt')
temp.close()
```

Comment: Please do not post code that is incomplete, s3 is not defined in that code snippet.

Comment: @HaziqNordin The code has been updated to show the reference to s3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file-handle you pass to the `s3.put_object` is at the final position, when you `.read` from it, it will return an empty string.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,50, (5,5)))
>>> temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+')
>>> df.to_csv(temp)
>>> temp.read()
''
```

A quick fix is to `.seek` back to the beginning...

```
>>> temp.seek(0)
0
>>> print(temp.read())
,0,1,2,3,4
0,11,42,40,45,11
1,36,18,45,24,25
2,28,20,12,33,44
3,45,39,14,16,20
4,40,16,22,30,37
```

Note, writing to disk is unnecessary, really, you could just keep everything in memory using a buffer, something like:

```
from io import StringIO # on python 2, use from cStringIO import StringIO
buffer = StringIO()

# Saving df to memory as a temporary file
df.to_csv(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
s3.put_object(buffer, Bucket = '[BUCKET NAME]', Key = 'test.txt')
```

Comment: The file size is around 10 million records. Would you still recommend keeping it in memory?

Comment: @jumpman23 that depends on your hardware specs. Either way should work. It's up to you.

Comment: Alright, that worked. I gave you the ole' green check mark.

Comment: I get "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing: TypeError"

Comment: i get t "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing: TypeError" too.

Comment: Just a quick update, the put_object method only takes keyword arguments and so the method call would look as such: `s3.put_object(Body=buffer, Bucket='[BUCKET NAME]', Key='test.txt')`